# MalformedXML when tagging an S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add a new set of tags to an S3 bucket using the AWS Java API, but I'm getting errors like this:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 5B3401CBDB133A88), S3 Extended Request ID: z1EDhMH5vN7o/9Tk93K5R1gWmmqUr49WjEz2rovD9HRCGJ54yHBfoTuUURvnpoizlCUK3Fy9qbY=
```

This is the code I have written (`newTags` is a `Map<String, String>`):

```
List<TagSet> tags = amazonS3.getBucketTaggingConfiguration(bucketName).getAllTagSets();
tags.add(new TagSet(newTags));
s3Service.setBucketTaggingConfiguration(bucketName, new BucketTaggingConfiguration(tags));
```

I'm not even using XML myself, and the error is unhelpful as to what is actually going wrong. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small mismatch between the Java API and the REST API. Have a look at the [PUT Bucket Tag request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTtagging.html). It's not explicitly stated, but it is implied that you can only have one `TagSet` per `Tagging` collection. BucketTaggingConfiguration, however, allows a list of TagSets.

Instead of adding a new TagSet, get the `Map<String, String>` from the first TagSet in the configuration, add your tags to that map, then create a new TagSet from that. Treat BucketTaggingConfiguration as though it only allows a single-item list of TagSets.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally figured this out but here is my code for how I got multiple tags placed on an S3 bucket.  Although the code implies I can add multiple tagSets but it seems to fail with the above error if I do so.  I just created a single TagSet with mu

```
public void TagS3(String bucketName, Map<String,String> tags){


    if(0 < tags.size()){
        TagSet ts = new TagSet(tags);
        BucketTaggingConfiguration btconfig = new BucketTaggingConfiguration();
        btconfig.withTagSets(ts);
        SetBucketTaggingConfigurationRequest tgRq =  new SetBucketTaggingConfigurationRequest(bucketName, btconfig);
        s3client.setBucketTaggingConfiguration(tgRq);
    }

}
```